# Router project for Windows that uses OSM maps

Tags: windows, openstreetmap

I'm looking for some router project (api, dll, executable) that supports OSM maps, external calls and runs on Windows. Any suggestions ?

Regards.

Router = Functionality that provides to the user the "best" way between given points.

Comment: More information would be helpful esp. about licenses, dependencies, langs, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [OSMSharp](http://www.osmsharp.com/) which probably works best under Windows as it is .NET, also there are some Java libraries like [GraphHopper](http://graphhopper.com/maps/) - have a look into http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing and for external calls over HTTP some Open Source Online routers could be suited http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers

Comment: I guess the common way to embedd Routing is pgRouting and a PostGIS DB backend. Depends all on your specific usecase...

Comment: @MaM if you like it difficult and slow, then yes ;)

Comment: Thanks Karussel. I'll accept your answer as right 'cause OSMSharp should solve the problem. But, I'll use another project, in linux I use OSRM, and I found a programmer that is working on Windows build. If someone would like to see it, https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/pull/979

Comment: @SaCi Maybe you ellaborate why not OSMSharp or GraphHopper?

Comment: @Karussell, familiarity only. I already use OSRM on linux, and the features I'll need I know that will be attended.